# Going back to previous page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

Is using JavaScript the most efficient way of navigating back to the previous page when a link or button is clicked?

What if JavaScript is disabled on the user's end (Which most people don't)?

Are there any known issues with cross-browsers? **Are there any browsers that don't support the `history.back()` function?**

I am using this code to go back to the previous page:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">[Go Back]</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the `Window history.back()` [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp), **all major browsers are supported**

Answer (score 3):

Try using this PHP code to generate your back button.

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) {
echo "<a href=\"".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]."\">[Go Back]</a>";
} else {
echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1);\">[Go Back]</a>";
}
```

Basically, you will only generate the JS link as a backup for when `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe that is the only way of going back using javascript, with the exception of writing this

```
history.go(-1); //this is the same thing
```

If javascript is disabled and you are not using any server software, then I don't know of any way outside of the user hitting the back button on the browser.

It appears to be supported by all major browsers according to w3schools - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Answer (score 2):

if you dont want to use client side scripting you can use server side like php:
try to set cookie in every page like this

```
$now = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
setcookie("back", $now);
```

now on your other pages :

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['back'])) 
{
echo "<a href='".$_COOKIE['back']."' target='_blank'>GO BACK</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event of Javascript being disabled, you can use Flash, Java, Silvelight, or other control based technology to assist in controlling this behavior as a fallback. Aside from that, you will be unable to control the users browser history navigation *if the user said no* by disabling support for it.

```
history.go(-1);
```

Is pretty much the defacto standard way of doing this, however, HTML5 has a more complex mechanism of controlling user history (using JavaScript), that doesn't necessarily involve the entire page switching (aka, on an element by element basis you can control the history)

See this article here for HTML5/Javascript method :  [HTML5 History Navigation](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript already implemented function `window.history.back();` and implement it wherever you need it, i used it on a button and worked great for me

Answer (score -1):

Just Follow This code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();">Back</a>
```